# datadog breaking tomcat on high load req (100req/sec)

Tags: tomcat, load-testing, datadog

Using datadog for tomcatload testing. While running with datadog, server is stopping every 2 mins and server is restarting giving this error. Running without datadog this is working just fine.

*A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000ffffa2811614, pid=10202, tid=0x0000ffffa1a3b1f0
JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_292-b10) (build 1.8.0_292-8u292-b10-0ubuntu1~18.04-b10)
Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.292-b10 mixed mode linux-aarch64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
V  [libjvm.so+0x3fb614]*

[Tomcat req pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rp1G.png)

Answer (score 1):

Reached out the AWS Support Team. This is bug with Open JDK. For this resolution we tried with a different JDK version and it worked